# reading the content of html file with variables inside it

Tags: php, html

I want to use file_get_contents() on an html file with 3 $vars written inside it and have those vars get the data assigned to them through $_POST.

example:

```
-html file-
    <html>
    .
    .
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>first name</td><td>last name</td><td>id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$fname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$id</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>

-php file-
    <?php
    .
    .
    $fname = $_POST('fname');
    $lname = $_POST('lname');
    $id = $_POST('id');
    $page = file_get_contents("test.html");
    echo $page;
    ?>
```

what I did for now was to set a comment `"<!--split-->"` where the vars go and then I explode() the file_get_contents("test.html"), attach the vars to the end of it and implode() the $page.
but it seems kinda intensive for such a small task and I hoped for a better solution.
I hope I have been clear enough with my question. if not please ask and I'll try to clarify more if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution which would require control of the `test.html` file:

1: Rename `test.html` to `test.php`

2: Edit `test.php` so it looks like this (notice I added the `echo` keyword, surrounded by PHP opening and closing tags):

```
<?php
//View (PHP file)
?>
<html>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>first name</td><td>last name</td><td>id</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</html>
```

3: Now, in your main PHP file, just `include` the PHP template file:

```
$fname = $_POST('fname');
$lname = $_POST('lname');
$id = $_POST('id');
include 'test.php';
```

Comment: This is an example of the Model-View-Controller (MVC) design. Your Model (data) consists of the values set into the $_POST array. The Controller is the top portion of your main PHP script, which sets the $_POST values into your local variables ($fname, $lname, $id). The View is the included HTML.

Comment: one last question for you. I tried getting the file content after i included it and then echoed it but the values were empty... how can I echo the page?

Comment: Just access the main PHP file directly in your browser (the file which contains the `include` line).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
-html file-
    <html>
    .
    .
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>first name</td><td>last name</td><td>id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>

-php file-
    <?php
    .
    .
    $fname = $_POST('fname');
    $lname = $_POST('lname');
    $id = $_POST('id');
    $page = sprintf(file_get_contents("test.html"),$fname,$lname,$id);
    echo $page;
    ?>
```

Comment: that's pretty cool actually. :) are there other nifty methods like this one?

Comment: Yup, tons of them: You can find them all at http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php